# Pause for loop until getting the response of an UIAlertController in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, alert, pause

I have been trying to get the answer from a user from the `UIAlertController`. The problem is that the code still runs while the `UIAlertController` is displayed. I would like to show the alert, and then wait until the user gives an answer to continue the code.

```
func showPopUp(name:String)->String{
   var gender = ""
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "What are you "+name+"?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Boy", style: .default, handler: { action in
       gender = "Boy"
   }))

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Girl", style: .default, handler: { action in
       gender = "Girl"
   }))

   self.present(alert, animated: true)
   return gender
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("This should appear before the alert")
    var characters: [String] = ["John", "Tom", "Martha"]
    for ch in characters{
       let a = showPopUp(name: ch)
       print(ch + " is a "+ a)
    }
}
```

I cannot put the code inside the action of the alert because it is inside a for loop, and therefore it continues without getting the gender.

Comment: Add a print when you do `gender = "Girl"` or `gender = "Boy"`. Add a print when you do `return gender`, you'll see the issue. Use a completion to retrieve the gender.

Comment: Use the completion block.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tZagTyc2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a completion handler, since the user input happens asynchronously, so you cannot return it using a synchronous `return`.

Unrelated to your issue, but you should be using String interpolation rather than `+` to concanate Strings.

```
func showPopUp(name:String, genderCompletion: @escaping (String)->()) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "What are you \(name)?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Boy", style: .default, handler: { action in
        genderCompletion("Boy")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Girl", style: .default, handler: { action in
        genderCompletion("Girl")
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let characters: [String] = ["John", "Tom", "Martha"]
    for ch in characters{
        showPopUp(name: ch, genderCompletion: { gender in
            print("\(ch) is a \(gender)")
        })
    }
}
```